# Author name length character limit?

Tags: comments, author, comment-form, username, characters

In comments, I want to limit author names. For example, the author's name should be no more than 10 characters.  I'm looking for a way to do this. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a filter called `get_comment_author` that you can hook into to modify a comment author's appearance.

```
add_filter( 'get_comment_author', function( $author, $comment_id, $comment ) {

    // limit to first 10 characters
    $author = substr( $author, 0, 10 );

    return $author;
}, 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It definitely works. I wish you a happy day!